# Roblox data not saving

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a script to save data (endings) of a player. But it doesn't work.

Here is the code of the saving script its on serverscriptservice:

```
local dataStore = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local data = dataStore:GetDataStore("Stats")


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local endingsFound = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    endingsFound.Name = "Endings"
    endingsFound.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local efValue = data:GetAsync(player.UserId.."-EndingsFound")
    
    if efValue ~= nil then
        player.leaderstats.endingsFound.Value = efValue
    end
    
    
end)


game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    
    
    local sucess, errorMsg = pcall(function()
        
        
        data:SetAsync(player.UserId.."-EndingsFound", player.leaderstats.endingsFound.Value)
        print("Saved data")
    end)
    
    
end)
```

and also here is code for the script that gives you endings:

```
local frame = script.Parent.Frame

local userInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local description = frame.Description
local title = frame.Title
local difficulty = frame.Rarity

local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Player = Players.LocalPlayer

local difficulties = {Color3.new(0, 250, 0), Color3.new(255, 251, 0), Color3.new(250, 0, 0), Color3.new(0.837415, 0.83743, 0.83743), Color3.new(0.580728, 0.0667277, 0)}
-- 1 = Easy 2 = Medium 3 = Hard 4 = Insane 5 = Impossible

function giveEnding(titleText, descriptionText, rarityColor, rarityText)
    frame.Visible = true
    description.Text = descriptionText
    title.Text = titleText
    difficulty.Text = rarityText
    difficulty.TextColor3 = difficulties[rarityColor]
    Player.leaderstats.Endings.Value += 1
    wait(5)
    frame.Visible = false
end

userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, _gameProcessed)
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
        giveEnding("test", "test", 1, "test")
    end
end)
```

I used this tutorial:

I expected it to work. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiyteFGW4u4

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Do you know what part of your code isn't working?

Comment: No to both questions.

Comment: Have you attempted to print out what you're storing with async before you save it and after it has been loaded. If you are attempting this in studio you also have to enable Data store for it to function

Comment: no I think and I enabled the datastore thing

Answer (score 0):

You might not have enabled data stored for studio. You have to publish the game to use data stored but the game can be kept private.
To enable Studio access in a published experience:

1.In the Home tab of the menu bar, navigate to the Settings section and click Game Settings. The Game Settings menu displays.
2.In the left-hand navigation of the Game Settings menu, click Security.
3.Enable the Enable Studio Access to API Services toggle.
4.Click the Save button.

Comment: i have enabled it already